# In Android 3.0 I am unable to use ndk-build to debug a native code error when there are no native code libraries

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

The specific error I am getting is the following:

```
07-01 15:58:03.674: A/DEBUG(14660): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-01 15:58:03.674: A/DEBUG(14660): Build fingerprint: 'Zebra/MC33/MC33:7.1.2/01-01-49-NG-00-A/7:user/release-keys'
07-01 15:58:03.674: A/DEBUG(14660): Revision: '0'
07-01 15:58:03.674: A/DEBUG(14660): ABI: 'arm64'
07-01 15:58:03.674: A/DEBUG(14660): pid: 14548, tid: 14548, name: x_pick_pack_app  >>> corp.cranegroup.corp.iplex_pick_pack_app <<<
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40b61c00
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x0   0000000000000001  x1   0000007ff08bb650  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000000000
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x4   0000000000000000  x5   88be1f8cfe791c83  x6   0000000000000000  x7   00000000fffffff5
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x8   0000000040b61c00  x9   88be1f8cfe791c83  x10  88be1f8cfe791c83  x11  0000000000000007
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x12  0000007ff08b9c70  x13  0000007f95690600  x14  0000007ff08b9d88  x15  0000000000000000
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x16  0000007f9761c008  x17  0000007f97545444  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007f956a3000
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x20  0000007f956a30a8  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007f86940f30  x23  0000007f86940f18
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x24  000000000000003f  x25  0000000000000003  x26  0000007ff08bb7d8  x27  000000000000003f
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     x28  0000000000000001  x29  0000007ff08bb930  x30  0000007f96020338
07-01 15:58:03.675: A/DEBUG(14660):     sp   0000007ff08bb790  pc   0000007f96020354  pstate 0000000060000000
07-01 15:58:04.147: A/DEBUG(14660): backtrace:
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #00 pc 0000000000018354  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+884)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #01 pc 0000000000017f30  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+60)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #02 pc 00000000000f2794  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+48)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #03 pc 0000000001fc3e40  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce+140)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #04 pc 0000000001fc5a60  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+236)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #05 pc 0000000001fbf778  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (android.os.Looper.loop+340)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #06 pc 00000000017bf758  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+516)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #07 pc 00000000000d2868  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #08 pc 00000000000df2b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+252)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #09 pc 000000000042a784  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #10 pc 000000000042c2f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_m+1188)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #11 pc 00000000003a372c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+56)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #12 pc 000000000061aa58  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x54e000) (java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke+180)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #13 pc 0000000002696a60  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+124)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #14 pc 0000000002697cbc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1702000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1432)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #15 pc 00000000000d2868  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #16 pc 00000000000df2b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+252)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #17 pc 000000000042a784  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #18 pc 000000000042a3dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+380)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #19 pc 0000000000345048  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+604)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #20 pc 00000000000a0794  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #21 pc 00000000000a2e84  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+692)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #22 pc 0000000000002260  /system/bin/app_process64
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #23 pc 000000000001a7d8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
07-01 15:58:04.148: A/DEBUG(14660):     #24 pc 0000000000001ccc  /system/bin/app_process64
```

With my application I have no native code libraries as part of the application that I have built and my Gradle is the following:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "corp.cranegroup.corp.iplex_pick_pack_app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }




    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'




}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
}
```

I have been unable to use the other answers on this site to get to the starting stage of debugging the actual error, whether it is because of null referencing or not. Almost everything else about native code seems to be about debugging your own written native code, however what I need is to see what is ending up being wrongly referenced so that I can fix the Java code that I am using. For reference the java is below

```
 public void goNext(View view) {
        if(view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
        }

        edtInput.setText(edtInput.getText().toString().trim());
        if (edtInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            txtError.setText("Please Enter Qty Picked Number");
        } else {
            // checking the network connection before starting the Activity
            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                String qtyEntered = edtInput.getText().toString();
                try{
                    //Check if there is a /n at the end, remove if there is one
                    if (qtyEntered.length() > 0 ) {
                        char lastCharacter = qtyEntered.charAt(qtyEntered.length() - 1);
                        if (lastCharacter == '\n') {
                            String barcode = qtyEntered.subSequence(0, qtyEntered.length() - 1).toString();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Barcode=" + barcode);
                            qtyEntered = barcode.trim();
                        }
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = null;

                if (Integer.parseInt(qtyEntered) < Integer.parseInt(_tasks.get(_taskIndex).getQty_to_pick())){

                    if (confirmShortPick(qtyEntered)){
                        if (getYNPickMore(qtyEntered)){
                            try{
                            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShortPickActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                            intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                            intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e ){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocToActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                            intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                            intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuantityActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ERROR_CODE", "Warning: You Selected to Pick the Full Qty, Please Pick Full Qty from ".concat(_fromLoc));
                        intent.putExtra("itemScanned", _curItem);
                        intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                        intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                        intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                        //startActivity(intent);
                    }

                } else {

                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocToActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                    intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                    intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                    intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
                //} else {
                //txtError.setText("Please Scan the correct Location for this trip");
                //}

                //if (Objects.equals(itemCode.trim(), _locCode.trim())) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "goNext: locCode matches");

                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            } else {
                txtError.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean getYNPickMore(String qtyPicked){
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message mesg) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        };
        final Boolean[] result = {false};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm Picked Qty of".concat(qtyPicked));
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to pick this item from a different location?");



        builder.setPositiveButton("Pick from other location", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                result[0] = true;
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());


            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Do nothing
                result[0] = false;
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        try{ Looper.loop(); }
        catch(RuntimeException e){}

        return result[0];
    }



    public boolean confirmShortPick(String qtyPicked) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message mesg) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        };

        final Boolean[] result = {false};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Confirm Picked Qty of".concat(qtyPicked));
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to short pick from this location?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Short Pick from here", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do nothing but close the dialog
                result[0] = true;
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Do nothing
                result[0] = false;
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        try{ Looper.loop(); }
        catch(RuntimeException e){}

        return result[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a bit more testing I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520173/a-libc-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-fault-addr-0x0-in-tid-17684-thread-3?rq=1) my problem, It seems as if there is an arbitary limit on the amount of work the main loop will handle at any one time, and this was the cause of the Sigsegv error.

So to handle my particular issue with the blocking/non-blocking alert dialog I did the following in my goNext function instead
'''Java

```
@Override
    public void goNext(View view) {
        if(view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
        }

        final Handler mHandlerThread = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                if (msg.what == 400){
                    txtError.setText(msg.getData().getString("Error"));
                } else if (msg.what == 100){
                    startActivity((Intent) msg.getData().getParcelable("Intent"));
                }
            }
        };

        Thread blockingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                Message message = new Message();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                edtInput.setText(edtInput.getText().toString().trim());
                if (edtInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    message.what = 400;
                    bundle.putString("Error","Please Enter Qty Picked Number");
                    message.setData(bundle);
                } else {
                    // checking the network connection before starting the Activity
                    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                        String qtyEntered = edtInput.getText().toString();
                        try{
                            //Check if there is a /n at the end, remove if there is one
                            if (qtyEntered.length() > 0 ) {
                                char lastCharacter = qtyEntered.charAt(qtyEntered.length() - 1);
                                if (lastCharacter == '\n') {
                                    String barcode = qtyEntered.subSequence(0, qtyEntered.length() - 1).toString();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Barcode=" + barcode);
                                    qtyEntered = barcode.trim();
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Intent intent = null;

                        if (Integer.parseInt(qtyEntered) < Integer.parseInt(_tasks.get(_taskIndex).getQty_to_pick())){

                            if (confirmShortPick(qtyEntered)){
                                if (getYNPickMore(qtyEntered)){
                                    try{
                                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShortPickActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                                        intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                                        intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                                        intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                                        //startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e ){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocToActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                                    intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                                    intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                                    intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                                    //startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            } else {
                                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuantityActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("ERROR_CODE", "Warning: You Selected to Pick the Full Qty, Please Pick Full Qty from ".concat(_fromLoc));
                                intent.putExtra("itemScanned", _curItem);
                                intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                                intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                                intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                                //startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        } else {

                            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocToActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("qtyEntered", qtyEntered);
                            intent.putExtra("taskArray", _tasks);
                            intent.putExtra("taskIndex", _taskIndex);
                            intent.putExtra("curTrip", _curTrip);
                            //startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        //} else {
                        //txtError.setText("Please Scan the correct Location for this trip");
                        //}

                        //if (Objects.equals(itemCode.trim(), _locCode.trim())) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "goNext: locCode matches");

                        if (intent != null) {
                            message.what = 100; //success
                            bundle.putParcelable("Intent",intent);
                            message.setData(bundle);
                        }

                    } else {
                        message.what = 400; //error
                        bundle.putString("Error","No network connection available.");
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    }
                }
                mHandlerThread.sendMessage(message);
            }
        });

        blockingThread.start();


        //new QuantityActivity.goNextAsynch().execute(view);

    }
```

By pulling the above into its own Thread I was able to get this to block the moving to the next activity whilst the application waited on user input from the AlertDialog.